# Multi-dimensional range queries with single column indexes

Tags: indexing, relational-database

I am reading a book that covers many database topics on a very high level, but doesn't dive deeper. It introduces multi-column indexes as a better way to query for 2 dimensional ranges. For example, this query is stated to be inefficient, if `latitude` and `longitude` each have single column indexes:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE latitude > 51.4946 AND latitude < 51.5079 AND longitude > -0.1162 AND longitude < -0.1004;
```

A better way would be to use a multicolumn index using `R-trees` spanning over both `latitude` and `longitude`.

I don't understand why first extracting information of `latitude > 51.4946` using a single columnd index and then extacting information `longitude > -0.1162 AND longitude < -0.1004` using the other single column index is inefficient? Can you use only 1 index per table when performing a query or is there some other reason for inefficiency?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but a single column index would not even cover all the criteria in the `WHERE` clause, which includes both latitude and longitude.  This, combined with that you are doing `SELECT *` means that a single column index would not have much chance of being used by your database.

Comment: yes, I agree with that.  The puzzling part is why 2 single column indexes, one on `latitude` and one on `longitude`, don't solve the problem.

Comment: As I mentioned, a single column index can't cover all the columns needed for the index to work.  It can't even cover the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Look into space filling curves and how they relate to indexing of geometric features.